# Minikube not showing CPU nor memory usage

Tags: kubectl, minikube

I have **successfully** installed kubectl and minikube in my MacbookPro (core i9 with 64 Gb in ram) and I have **successfully** deployed a pod with a number of replicas. I have also started up the Kubernetes web UI, and the final application runs **perfectly well**. However, in the Kubernetes Web Console, I can only see "a dash" in CPU usage and Memory columns. Why? Did I forget to set up something? (Just as a reference, please take a look at the attached image)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 hours of digging, I found by myself the solution:

First, I had to install the "metrics-server":

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

After that, enable it:

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

That's it !![image]

Comment: The addon seems to ship with minikube 1.24, or is downloaded automatically. I didn't have to run your first command, either way.